# Can't prefetch local json file with Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I need to use an autocomplete that read a local json file and I'm using Typeahead.js.

I have this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/9/) that it's working to fetch a external json file. And I tried to adapt this code in the following way and faild:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('country'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: "../app/helpers/countries.json"
    });


    dataSource.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        highlight: true
    }, {
        displayKey: 'country',
        source: dataSource.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```

countries.json

```
[
  {
        "country": "Holland",
        "city": "Amsterdam"
    },
    {
        "country": "Belgium",
        "city": "Brussel"
    },
    {
        "country": "Germany",
        "city": "Berlin"
    },
    {
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Paris"
    }
]
```

The error message on the browser:

> client.js:995 GET http://localhost:3000/app/helpers/countries.json 406
>   (Not Acceptable)

According to this [typeahead examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) it should work and I don't know why.

Comment: You've written invalid json. You need to use quotation marks around the property names, **AS WELL** as the values. JS can process that as an **array of** object literals, which is actually different to JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I tried what you told and the error message remains...

Comment: So have you tried using AJAX with this? - I just tried something similar, as I'm building my own **HIGHLY** bespoke JS framework, one feature is including external files via `ajax`, provided you've got **valid** `json`, it works. If it's **invalid** then yes, it fails.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V yes I also tried exactly the way you did. The way I did is not according the best practice but it should work too. Maybe the error derives from the Rails framework and the folder that I'm calling it.

Comment: have you tried playing around with request headers? - You may also need to play around with the back end, who knows, it *could* be a back end bug, but I'm *assuming* you haven't set the request header in your JS? :P

Comment: Oh yes I did it too. Thank you for your attention and I solved the problem in a weird way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741206/do-rails-protect-from-reading-local-json-file-through-javascript

Comment: No problem at all, happy to have *tried* to help! :)

Comment: Yeah, you're welcome dude!