# Do Rails protect from reading local json file through javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to read json file using javascript with this code:

```
$.getJSON("app/helpers/data.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
    });
});
```

but all I get from the browser is this:

> GET http://localhost:3001/app/helpers/data.json 404 (Not Found)

They always understand to search in terms of *url path instead of file path inside the code folders*.

And when I try to read in controller I received the correct data:

```
@file = JSON.parse(File.read('app/helpers/data.json'))

{"list"=>[{"label"=>"lbl1", "category"=>"cat1", "desc"=>"desc1"}, {"label"=>"lbl2", "category"=>"cat1", "desc"=>"desc2"}, {"label"=>"lbl3", "category"=>"cat1"}]}
```

**not so good solution:**

The only way that I could display this json in js file is assigning the variable in controller and sending this variable to the js file with the [gem gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

on top of head application.html.erb:

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

controller action:

```
gon.json_data = JSON.parse(File.read('json path'))
```

js file:

```
console.log(gon.json_data);
```

Obs 1: This approach using gem gon makes the app *much more slow* when you have to read databases with some thousands records in rails (5.5k and spent 500ms to load it each time!)

Obs 2: I imagine the *security issues* when you have access to local files using javascript but it seems that I'm the only person in the world that have this "problem" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the .json and make it available to the webserver, and therefore to the client, you should put it in the `public/`-folder. The `app/helpers` folder is generally not available to the client, unless routed otherwise.

From the controller you could then do

```
@file = JSON.parse(File.read('public/helpers/data.json'))
```

Here, you would then access it from the browser as

```
$.getJSON("helpers/data.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and it seems to be reasonable but this error persists for some reason...

Comment: Is data.json dynamic or static JSON file? Does it read from the controller still, after moving file and changing path?

Comment: it is static json file and the controller is no longer reading

Comment: If you try reading as `"#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/helpers/data.json"`, to ensure the full root. Also doublecheck that the path is in fact `public/helpers/data.json`, and not in app-folder as before. You could try accessing it as `localhost:3000/helpers/data.json` to ensure that it's there.

Comment: Thank you a lot and it is really terrible that I checked what you told and the problem persists...I'll keep verifying it carefully.

Comment: What's the error from console, when you're trying to read it there?

Comment: unfortunately the error message is exactly the same as before. I'm using rails 5.1.5